# Restricted User Account Creation

Tags: server, user-management

I was once given a shell account (for IRC) that allowed me read/write access to my home folder only.

The first time I logged in, it forced me to change my password too.

Say I wanted to create a new user with this type of structure. Any guides I can look into?

Comment: Hi did you solve your problem here? It was clear the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems you where allowed to login with a kind of [Restricted shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html).
Or maybe you where *contained* by a [tool like `Jailkit`](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/index.html#download).  You can find useful [this blog page too.](http://www.marthijnvandenheuvel.com/2010/03/10/how-to-create-a-chroot-ssh-user-in-ubuntu/)

When you create a new user you will be asked for username, password, shell...
If `rbash` is installed in your system you can select it.
It's possible to force the user to change the password at the first login. 
If the user was just been created you can always force his password to expire with
`sudo chage -d 0 TheUserThatHaveToChangePassword`

**Restricted Shell**
If  bash  is  started  with  the name rbash, or the -r option is supplied at invocation, the shell becomes restricted.  A restricted shell is used to set up  an  environment  more  controlled than the standard shell.  It behaves identically to bash with some limitation:

```
 -      changing directories with cd
 -      setting or unsetting the values of SHELL, PATH, ENV, or BASH_ENV
 -      specifying command names containing /
 -      specifying a filename containing a / as an argument to the .  builtin command
 -      specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the -p option to the  hash builtin command
 -      importing function definitions from the shell environment at startup
 -      parsing the value of SHELLOPTS from the shell environment at startup
 -      redirecting output using the >, >|, <>, >&, &>, and >> redirection operators
 -      using the exec builtin command to replace the shell with another command
 -      adding  or deleting builtin commands with the -f and -d options to the enable builtin command
 -      using the enable builtin command to enable disabled shell builtins
 -      specifying the -p option to the command builtin command
 -      turning off restricted mode with set +r or set +o restricted.
```

These restrictions are enforced after any startup files are read.
**When a command that is found to be a shell script is executed, rbash turns off any  restrictions in the shell spawned to execute the script.**
This means you may need  [some work more to enforce the security.](http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/how-to-restrict-access-with-rbash/)